# How to extract Hours and Minutes (from Date) as a number in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

What I did:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI') FROM dual;
```

What i got:

```
13:30
```

What I want :

```
13.50
```

I also tried the EXTRACT function then summed hours and minutes but still not working.

Comment: So you don't really want hours *and* minutes, you want *hours* (including fractional parts of hours), right? And do you need the format `13.50` or will `13.5` suffice?

Answer (score 6):

If you want the actual time (not just hours and minutes), you can do:

```
select ( sysdate - trunc(sysdate) ) * 24, sysdate
from dual;
```

If you just want just hours and minutes:

```
select extract(hour from current_timestamp) + extract(minute from current_timestamp) / 60
from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time-of-day (hours, minutes and seconds) expressed in fractional hours, then you can use

```
( sysdate - trunc(sysdate) ) * 24
```

as Gordon has shown already.

If you want to truncate the seconds and just convert the hour and minute into hours, then you can use

```
( trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - trunc(sysdate) ) * 24
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `extract()` functionality to get the hour and minutes. Note that this requires converting dates to a timestamp datatype (or using systimestamp in your example).

Once you have the hours and minutes you can do arithmetic on them and format them to fit your needs. For instance:

```
with cte as ( 
    select to_timestamp('2018-03-31 13:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as dt 
    from dual
) ,  tt as (
    select extract(hour from dt) as hr
           , round(extract(minute from dt)/60,2) as mn
    from cte
)
select to_char(hr,'09')||trim(to_char(mn,'.00')) as your_time
from tt
/
```

... will display `13.50`.

Here's [a SQL Fiddle demo for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc59c/2).

Comment: Rounding isn't exactly what the OP was doing. `TO_CHAR(..., 'HH24:MI')` truncates, it doesn't round.